# Configuring and running gulp to watch and compile sass

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have configured my gulp file to run certain tasks, and when I run the file I get this error:
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask]

Here is my code in the gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('./css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', [ 'sass' ]);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    var files = [
        './*.html',
        './css/*.css',
        './js/*.js',
        './img/*.{png, jpg, gif}'
    ];
    browserSync.init(files, {
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'browser-sync' ], function () {
    gulp.start('sass:watch');
});
```

I think the problem is caused by the syntax I am using with this line:

```
gulp.task('default', [ 'browser-sync' ], function () {
        gulp.start('sass:watch');
    });
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: you should take a look at gulp 4

Comment: I am still busy looking, il try to figure it out

Comment: You are right, that default task is a problem.  Find a migrating to gulp4 guide.  And lose `gulp.start` too.

Comment: Ok @Mark thanks, let me try migrating